# Changing the layer order of subfigures

Tags: floats, subfloats, layers

I have a five-image figure that I need to fit in one vertical column.

Because the tops of the images have a decent amount of white space, I introduced some negative space after each subfigure. However, now the white space at the top of the second subfigure covers the caption of the first subfigure, and the third for the second etc.
[image: White space covering up the previous caption.]

Is it possible to have the subfigures drawn in reverse order so the captions go on top of the whitespace in the next subfigure?

Here's a minimal snippet for a 2-image figure.

```
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2in]{picture1.png}
        \caption{cap1}
    \end{subfigure}\\[-10ex]
    
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2in]{picture2.png}
        \caption{Original iteration space of one loop in chain.}
    \end{subfigure}\\[-10ex]
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but couldn't you just crop your figures?

Comment: See the graphicx manual, page 10: [clip=true, trim=0 0 0 10ex]